# Is it possible to pass a click option at the end of the entire command?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-click

Is it possible to set a `click.option` on a `click.group` but pass the option in the end of the entire command?

```
@click.option(
    '-d', '--debug',
    help="change to debug mode")
@click.group()
def cli(ctx, **kwargs):
    """
    help message
    """

@click.command()
def version():
    """
    version
    """
    pass
```

And the desired command would look like this:

```
./cli.py version -d
```

But this fails with:

> Error: no such option: -d

Answer (score 2):

One way to to set a `click.option` on a `click.group` but pass the option in the end of the entire command is to inherit from `click.Group`, and customize the code which invokes the commands.

This question was partially answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44229795/7311767).  From that question we will use the custom class: `GroupWithCommandOptions`.

#### Custom Class:

```
import click

class GroupWithCommandOptions(click.Group):
    """ Allow application of options to group with multi command """

    def add_command(self, cmd, name=None):
        click.Group.add_command(self, cmd, name=name)

        # add the group parameters to the command
        for param in self.params:
            cmd.params.append(param)

        # hook the commands invoke with our own
        cmd.invoke = self.build_command_invoke(cmd.invoke)
        self.invoke_without_command = True

    def build_command_invoke(self, original_invoke):

        def command_invoke(ctx):
            """ insert invocation of group function """

            # separate the group parameters
            ctx.obj = dict(_params=dict())
            for param in self.params:
                name = param.name
                ctx.obj['_params'][name] = ctx.params[name]
                del ctx.params[name]

            # call the group function with its parameters
            params = ctx.params
            ctx.params = ctx.obj['_params']
            self.invoke(ctx)
            ctx.params = params

            # now call the original invoke (the command)
            original_invoke(ctx)

        return command_invoke
```

#### Using Custom Class:

To use the custom class, pass the `cls` parameter to [`@click.group()`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/api/#click.group)
decorator like:

```
@click.group(cls=GroupWithCommandOptions)
```

Then create a [`click.CommandCollection`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/api/#click.CommandCollection) using the group

```
cli = click.CommandCollection(sources=[group1])
```

The command collection is important because we need to control when the group is invoked, and
`CommandCollection`'s do not invoke their group, so we can do it ourselves at the appropriate time.

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The
[`@click.group()`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/api/#click.group) decorator usually instantiates a
[`click.Group`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/api/#click.Group) object but allows this behavior to be over ridden
with the `cls` parameter. So it is a relatively
easy matter to inherit from [`click.Group`](http://click.pocoo.org/6/api/#click.Group) in our own class and over ride the desired methods.

In this case we over ride `click.Group.add_command()` to add the group parameters to the command
and then monkey patch the command's `invoke()` method so can call the group invoke before command invoke to allow
it to process its options which were specified on the command.

#### Test Code:

```
@click.group(cls=GroupWithCommandOptions)
@click.option('-d', '--debug', help="change to debug mode", is_flag=True)
def group1(**kwargs):
    """Our great program"""
    click.echo('debug: %s' % kwargs['debug'])


@group1.command()
@click.pass_context
def version(ctx):
    """Show the Version"""
    click.echo('show version here')


cli = click.CommandCollection(sources=[group1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    commands = (
        'version -d',
        '-d version',
        'version',
        '--help',
        'version --help',
    )

    import sys, time
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
    print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
    for cmd in commands:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print('-----------')
            print('> ' + cmd)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            cli(cmd.split())

        except BaseException as exc:
            if str(exc) != '0' and \
                    not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
                raise
```

#### Test Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Python Version: 3.6.2 (default, Jul 17 2017, 23:14:31)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
-----------
> version -d
debug: True
show version here
-----------
> -d version
Error: no such option: -d
-----------
> version
debug: False
show version here
-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  version  Show the Version
-----------
> version --help
Usage: test.py version [OPTIONS]

  Show the Version

Options:
  -d, --debug  change to debug mode
  --help       Show this message and exit.
```

Comment: I was looking for something easier. What I did eventually was to create a decorated that defines X number of click options. I applied this decorator on the desired click.commands. That is definitely a workaround but it lets me control all common options in one place without having to add a lot of code

Comment: I am not sure how much easier this could be. Using the custom class requires two lines of.code, one of which you already have, but will need to edit.

Answer (score -1):

Achieving this using click is impossible as an option belongs to it's command. An option that is available to all commands should belong to the group that encloses the commands.

A couple of implementation examples for achieving that can be found here: 
https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/108